# How can I run command from Java code and read the output?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am writing a code to execute a command and reading the output
If I run the command on command prompt, it looks like this [image]

Command is

`echo 'excellent. awesome' | java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin`

Command produces multi line output. How can I print this output in my java code?

I have written following code, but it produces output as command itself that is

`echo 'excellent. awesome' | java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin`

rather than actual command output as we can see it in the screenshot

```
    final String cmd = "java -cp \"*\" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin";
    final String path = "C:/Project/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-29/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-29"; 

    String input = "excellent";
    String cmdString = "echo '" +input + "' | " + cmd;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdString,null, new File(path));
    process.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine();   
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate - *it produces output as command itself rather than actual command output*?

Comment: I think you might be getting the args wrong. The first argument is only the command name, the other on is a string array containing the parameters to the command.

Comment: You could access `SentimentModel` programmatically, which would be much easier than piping from a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ProcessBuilder:

```
try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("your command here");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
        }
        p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```